# Why recursive function with linked list does not work?

Tags: c, list, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I have a big problem, I'm doing a project with dynamic linked lists in c, simulating a world fixture, the list works perfectly, the insert, advance, etc. functions work perfectly, only precisely in this function something fails and I still don't have clear what the problem is. The idea is this:
I have a list with their respective nodes, each one of them has the information of a World Cup team, among all the data I have the score of that team, what this recursive function is supposed to do is print the score with its respective team from highest to lowest recursively, but for some reason it ends up failing

Another important information is that the list is charged with a precharge function that read elements from a file and save that elements in the list.

the code is much longer but tried to give as much information as possible

```
void showsteamsScore(List *lis,int maxscore){
    
    Team aux=copy(*lis);
    
    if(maxscore==-1){
        
        system("pause");
        menu(lis);

    }else{
        
        if(!isOos(lis)){
            
            forwards(lis);
            if(showactualScore(aux)==maxscore){
                
                printf("%s-%d\n",showCountry(aux),showactualScore(aux));
                
            }else{
                
                showsteamsScore(lis,maxscore);
                
            }
                
        }else{

            reset(lis);
            showsteamsScore(lis,maxscore-1);


        }

    }
    
    }
```

A brief description of the functions used in this code

isOos(is out of structure) indicates when there are no
more nodes to traverse

reset: return to the beginning, to the first node of the
list

forwards: forwards between nodes in a list

copy: copy from a node information of a team

I tried everything but most of the things did not work or the program broke, changing the variables, the order of execution, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "the program broke"? What was exactly the error message? Stack Overflow?